# junit does not find tests in scala class but does find tests in java class (maven project)

Tags: java, scala, maven, junit

I have a maven program, it compiles fine.
I have this scala class ./src/test/java/ResearchTest.scala

```
import org.junit.Test

class ResearchTest
{



 @Test
  def justAnExample(): Unit = {
    System.out.println("This test method should be running SCALA")
  }
}
```

When I run mvn clean test, it does not run any tests, this is the output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< poc:webIntTest11111 >-------------------------
[INFO] Building webIntTest11111 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from paypal-snapshots:     http://nexus.paypal.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/paypal/risk/ars/url-udf/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ webIntTest11111 ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/drimoch/IdeaProjects/webIntTest11111/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ webIntTest11111 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ webIntTest11111 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ webIntTest11111 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ webIntTest11111 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/drimoch/IdeaProjects/webIntTest11111/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ webIntTest11111 ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.356 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-14T16:46:49+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also have this java class ./src/test/java/Tests.java:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class Tests {
    @Test
   public void justAnExample() {
        System.out.println("This test method should be run JAVA");
    }
}
```

When I run mvn clean test now, its runs this test.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< poc:webIntTest11111 >-------------------------
[INFO] Building webIntTest11111 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from paypal-snapshots: http://nexus.paypal.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/paypal/risk/ars/url-udf/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ webIntTest11111 ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/drimoch/IdeaProjects/webIntTest11111/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ webIntTest11111 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ webIntTest11111 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ webIntTest11111 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ webIntTest11111 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/drimoch/IdeaProjects/webIntTest11111/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ webIntTest11111 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running Tests
This test method should be run JAVA
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.054 s - in Tests
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.514 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-14T16:59:10+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to run tests in scala, what should I change?

also, this is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>webIntTest11111</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paypal.risk.ars.bigdata.webintl</groupId>
            <artifactId>webintl-services</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paypal.risk.ars.zonkey</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-utils</artifactId>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paypal.risk.ars.bigdata.webintl</groupId>
            <artifactId>webintl-services</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I think you'll need `@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])` unless you use ScalaTest with Maven.

Comment: I gave up and now I'm simply using Scalatest, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

When you run maven test. You are actually using the surefire plugin. By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:

- "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
- "**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
- "**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests"
- "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".

I would suggest that you add a build.sbt file to your project and handle scala classes with sbt. However if you need to do this with maven then you need to add the [scalatest-maven-plugin](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin) to your pom, move scala test classes to src/test/scala. And then you should be able to test with maven.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, but after doing that, I was able to run scalatest tests, But not Junit tests, as I wanted